# XSS Value in Input Tag

Tags: coldfusion, xss

I'm looking for some advice on securing my code from vulnerabilities. Below are two lines that I have questions about.

```
<input type="hidden" name="criteria" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="0" />
```

The code was scanned with IBM's App Scan and the results came back that the test was able to inject a script (XSS) into the parameter 'criteria' and 'search'. I found a few examples of this online (inside  tag), but didn't see a solid solution. Based on this information,what would be the easiest way to sanitize the values to prevent XSS?

Comment: The test is pointing out that criteria and search could have anything in it, not just a benign blank and 0. Could criteria and search field be eliminated or saved as a session variable rather than pushing it over a form?

Comment: Most likely, no. I'm don't want to change the code too much if I don't have to - simply doing bug fixes. Is there no easy way to secure both of these inputs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong end of the problem. What you've shown us there is just that you have a form with some form fields in it. That is not a problem.

What *is* the problem is that if there's a form... there must be a form submission. And you'll have some process that *receives* the form submission and does something with it. Part of "doing something with it" should probably be "sanitising it from XSS injection".

How you handle this depends on why you're being audited, and how strenuously they require you to guard for that sort of thing.

The easiest first thing to do is to enable "Enable Global Script Protection" in Settings in CFAdmin. That's just a checkbox. I dunno how comprehensive or well-implemented this is, but it might be all you need to placate your audit.

Secondly... your WAF should block this sort of thing automatically. If you don't have a WAF, get one. Foundeo do [FuseGuard](https://foundeo.com/security/), which I have never used, but expect it to be pretty good as the Foundeo bods know what they're doing, and it's also a CFML-specific solution.

Third: address your code. This could be as easy as intercepting all inbound form, URL, CGI and cookie values, and making sure they have no XSS vectors in them. The basic level here is to prohibit anything with `<script>` blocks being passed to your application. However what you need to do is more comprehensive than that, and outwith the scope of a StackOverflow Q&A. Go have a look at what the OWASP bods have to say about XSS mitigation. Start here: "[Cross-site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)".

If you're going for PCI compliance, you'll likely have to do *all three* of those. Even if either one of the first two ought to be all right. PCI isn't about being sensible, it's about PCI auditors extorting money from you. So you kinda go along with what they say.